# Returning a Class with property of type List(Of T) in WCF

Tags: vb.net, wcf

I have a service which returns a `<DataContract> Public Class Character`. That Class has a property `<DataMember> Public Property Modifiers As ModernList(Of Modifier)`. Modifier is a DataContract as well: the problem here is with ModernList. ModernList(Of T) is my implementation of a List with some modifications; it derives from System.Collections.Generic.List(Of T). Now, I know that when returning derived classes in WCF, we should decorate the base class with `<KnownType>`, but, well, I can't decorate List(Of T) with that. Also, I can't decorate my ModernList(Of T) with `<DataContract>`and its Item property with `<DataMember>` because Item is not overridable in List(Of T). So, what do I do?

Edit: I've just remembered I could instead make an Item property which shadows the original property      and decorate it with `<DataMember>`, but then I discovered this:

> Property 'Item' in type 'DKMainService.Infraestrutura.Jogo.Equipamento' cannot be serialized because serialization of indexed properties is not supported.

Edit 2: Funny thing, I can perfectly make a method which returns a ModernList(Of T) and it works nicely. The problem is with returning classes which contains properties of type ModernList(Of T).

Comment: Don't decorate the "index" property in your shadow Item with the [DataMember] attribute. You can use ServiceKnownType on the service to define the known types if you aren't able to attribute them. https://abhishekdv.wordpress.com/2013/06/10/serviceknowntype-and-knowntype-attribute-in-wcf/

Comment: That wasn't enough. I tried decorating the Character Class with `<KnownType(ModernList(Of Modifier))>`, as well as the method with `<ServiceKnownType(ModernList(Of Modifier))>`, no success. I've now rewritten my ModernList(Of T) completely, building it up from the ground, instead of inheriting List(Of T) so I could decorate it with KnownType and DataContract, no success either. I think it's a problem with Generics. It's strange though, because in the Character class it's well defined as ModernList(Of Modifier). Also, as I said in the OP, methods returning ModernList works normally.

Answer (score 0):

Well, WCF tricked me all the time. WCF was telling me that "The server did not provide a meaningful reply; this might be caused by a contract mismatch, a premature session shutdown or an internal server error." Now, that didn't tell me nothing. I always thought that the problem were with my ModernList because if the list was null, then everything would work fine. Today, after racking my brain for hours because of this, somehow, for some reason, WCF decided to change it's error message, providing me with a way more clear one, letting me know where the problem was precisely: it was in one property of a Class which was the type of a property of one of the Modifiers in the ModernList(Of Modifier)! See: an Enum `Enum Knowledges` didn't had a member with value `0` assigned to it (the first member had value `1`). Then, there was that class which had a property of type `Knowledges`. That property, in turn, wasn't initialized in construction and wasn't nullable either. Now you probably have realized the problem here: Enums are a Value type, thus they can't be assigned with `Null`; their default value is `0`. My Enum didn't have a member with value `0` though, so when it was deserialized it tried to find a member with value `0`, since it couldn't be null, and that didn't exist.